# How to create Image File inside Internal Cache Directory in Android

Tags: android, android-file

I want to have image.png inside cache/images/ in Internal Storage of Android.

I am not able to have it with following code:

```
File directory = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "images");
directory.mkdirs();


File mypath=new File(directory,"image.png");

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

    bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With the above code I am not even able to create a directory named images. Pls help, I am beginner.

Comment: have you added permission?

Comment: I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in manifest.  But I don't think internal storage requires that permission.

Comment: What makes you think you aren't able to create a directory named images? Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```java
File sd = getCacheDir();
File folder = new File(sd, "/myfolder/");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    if (!folder.mkdir()) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot create a directory!");
    } else {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
}

File fileName = new File(folder,"mypic.jpg");

try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(fileName));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks. I was missing '/' both the times.

Comment: `Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot create a directory!");`. You should add a `return;` statement there as it makes no sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: `else {
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }`. You should also check the return value of mkdirs(). And why are you using mkdir() AND mkdirs()? Mkdirs() alone would do.

Comment: @greenapps go learn the fundamentals of coding. or go paint green color on your apps !

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it like this...

```
//create file
File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

//draw image if created successfully
if (file.createNewFile()) {

//initialize image BitMap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

//initialize canvas and paint object
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

//design part goes here using Paint and Canvas
...

//get file output stream and draw design on image file
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
}
```