# generate image and share with intent without permission

Tags: android, image, android-intent, share

I have a function that allow the user to share a text on social media and other messaging apps.
I would like to allow the user to send this text as an image. I found how to generate image from text but it always require permissions and I can't figure out if there is a way that would work without requiring any permission. Is this something possible?

Current function:

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getTitle());
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getText());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share using"));
```

I searched around and tried to find if I could generate it to cache and or a folder that don't require permission but haven't found anything that would work yet.

Any insight on this is appreciated, thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Use the `getCacheDir()` method on `Context` to get a location to use. Use `FileProvider` to make it available to other apps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I'll investigate what is possible with this!

Comment: I managed to make it work with what you pointed to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches using the suggestion of **CommonsWare** I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
TextPaint tPaint = new TextPaint();
tPaint.setTextSize(30);
tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

StaticLayout layoutBody = new StaticLayout(textToShare, tPaint, 600, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, false);
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(layoutBody.getWidth(), layoutBody.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        
Canvas cs = new Canvas(image);
layoutBody.draw(cs);
cs.drawBitmap(dest, 0, 0, null);
```

Followed by what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733663/how-to-create-image-file-inside-internal-cache-directory-in-android) posting it here in case it helps anyone